# Regex validate PIN Codewars

Tags: javascript

For this Codewars challenge, I cannot understand why the logic is not working. I've found other solutions, but would like to understand why this is not working:

ATM machines allow 4 or 6 digit PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digits.

If the function is passed a valid PIN string, return true, else return false.

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  
  const splitPin = pin.toString().split('')
  const finalArr = [];
  
for (let i = 0; i < splitPin.length; i++){
  
  if (!Number.isInteger(pin[i])){
    return false;
  } else if (Number.isInteger(pin[i])){
    finalArr.push(pin[i]);
  }
}
  if(finalArr.length === 4 || finalArr.length === 6){
    console.log(finalArr.length)
    return true;
  } 
  
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to access `pin[i]` when `pin` is an integer?

Comment: If the element of the splitPin array is an integer, it should be pushed into finalArr. Or at least, that's the intention

Comment: Carefully look at how and where you are using `splitPin`. You create it to presumably check each digit of `pin`, but you are currently doing so by using `pin[i]` itself. Do you mean `!Number.isInteger(splitPin[i])` instead?

Comment: what does your question have to do with regex?

Comment: Yup. That's absolutely correct. Thank you! Still failing 1 test but I will keep looking into it.

Comment: Why is finalArr a const instead of a let?

Comment: Try using `parseInt(splitPin[i])` instead. If pin is a string, splitting it will return an array of strings and `Number.isInteger` won't parse the string that you're passing in. It'll return false for each entry because they'll be of type string.

Answer (score 1):

There are some double checks that you don't need to do but you are doing because you're not sure what you're expecting.

Like the type for `pin`.

`const splitPin = pin.toString().split('')` works either way for a string or number value, because you are expecting a string, the call to `.toString` is unneccesary

But also that you're using `Number.isInteger` - this function will only return true if the parameter is of type integer.

But since `pin` is a string and splitting it returns an array of strings, the `Number.isInteger` call will always return false.

Try using `isNaN` instead. Then check for `!isNaN(pin[0])` (Thanks to cyberbrain).

You can streamline the function from:

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  
  const splitPin = pin.toString().split('')
  const finalArr = [];
  
for (let i = 0; i < splitPin.length; i++){
  
  if (!Number.isInteger(pin[i])){
    return false;
  } else if (Number.isInteger(pin[i])){
    finalArr.push(pin[i]);
  }
}
  if(finalArr.length === 4 || finalArr.length === 6){
    console.log(finalArr.length)
    return true;
  } 
  
}
```

to something cleaner:

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  const acceptedLengths = [4, 6]
  const splitPin = pin.toString().split('')
  const finalArr = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < splitPin.length; i++){
    // You don't need to do an else, since you're only
    // checking for one condition.
    // just return directly
    if (!isNaN(pin[i])){
      finalArr.push(pin[i]);
    }

    return
  }
  
  return acceptedLengths.includes(finalArr.length)
}
```

or even something like this:

```
function validatePIN(pin) {
  // Set a variable for the accepted length
  const acceptedPINLength = [4, 6];

  // If we have to check if a value in pin is an integer or not
  // then the pin variable is a string and can't be a number.
  // So skip the .toString and just split it directly.
  const numbersArray = pin.split('')
    .filter((entry) => !isNaN(entry))

  // if strength is 4 or 6, return true, else false
  return acceptedPINLength.includes(numbersArray.length)
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use only for loop + if statements, but this is also interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @OliGarc333 I made an edit. To keep in the for loop and if statement. But I cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: This solution still accepts PINs of any length if they just contain exactly 4 or 6 digits. (And the rest non-digits.)

Comment: another flaw of this solution is, that `!== NaN` just always returns `true`, so it doesn't check for real digits. You would have to use `isNaN()` - and then you don't need the `parseInt()`

Comment: @cyberbrain that's true. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I would say: no loop required at all, you don't have to filter any characters:

```
function validatePIN(pin) {
  const acceptedPINLength = [4, 6];
  return acceptedPINLength.includes(pin.length) && !isNaN(pin);
}
```

(Thanks to @Amats for the elegant solution with the acceptedPINLength.)

Comment: `length` is not invoked I believe. Also does `isNaN` sufficiently cover all cases?

Comment: @greenfrog you are right, `length` is a property, not a function - I updated my answer to fix this typo. Which cases do you think that `isNaN()` would not cover? I'm looking for a string that just consist of digits, and as 6 is the maximum length, this should be a number for JavaScript.